# C StdLib malloc From (N)ASM

Tags: c, assembly, malloc, nasm, standard-library

I'm looking to call `malloc()` from an ASM file.
In ASM:

```
extern malloc
```

didn't work. I would like to link the CStdLib.

Comment: What? I'm talking about from a NASM file. You're talking about from a C file. I'm well aware of the call from inside C. I love how you -voted me and you're completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly does "didn't work" mean?  You need to do more than just use `extern`, you need to link against the C Library.  The easiest way is to use `gcc` to link.  As you didn't mention if your code is 32 bit or 64, I will go with 32 bit.  The process is basically the same for 64 bit.

```
extern exit, printf, malloc, free

global main

BUFFER_SIZE     equ 27

section .data
fmtstr      db  "%s", 10, 0

section .text
main:

    push    BUFFER_SIZE
    call    malloc
    add     esp, 4 * 1
    mov     esi, eax

    xor     ecx, ecx
    mov     edx, 97

.FillBuffer:
    mov     byte [esi +  ecx], dl
    inc     edx
    inc     ecx
    cmp     ecx, BUFFER_SIZE - 1
    jne     .FillBuffer

    mov     byte [esi + ecx], 0

    push    esi
    push    fmtstr
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4 * 2

    push    esi
    call    free
    add     esp, 4 * 1

    push    0
    call    exit
    add     esp, 4 * 1
```

and the makefile:

```
APP=malloctest

all: $(APP) clean

$(APP): $(APP).o    
    gcc -o $(APP) $(APP).o 

$(APP).o: $(APP).asm
    nasm -f elf $(APP).asm 

clean:
    rm $(APP).o
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! However, I compiled the .asm file with the following (x64 machine x86 code): `nasm -f elf32 -o exec file.asm` and `ld -m elf_i386`. This is what I meant whe I said "did not work": http://gyazo.com/c11f7d980d623ee163eb188a8c763cc0

Comment: `-lc` to ld. Probably also need `-I/lib/ld-linux.so.2` or wherever your system puts it.